# django admin list sum fields

Tags: django, django-admin

I'd like to combine the same table data from the inventory admin page list. 
My admin.py is as follows

**admin.py**

```
class CounselAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('counsel_idx', 'show_firm_url', 'answer_count', 'counsel_status', 'deleted', 'register_date',)
    search_fields = ('counsel_status',)
    list_filter = ('counsel_status',)

    def show_firm_url(self, obj):
        return format_html("<a href='/admin/counsel/view/{0}'>{1}</a>", obj.counsel_idx, obj.counsel_title)

    show_firm_url.short_description = 'title'
```

For example, I would like to put it together in this way
show_firm_url

```
The data in show_firm_url is = TITLE TEST
answer_count is = 7
in case of

TITLE TEST (answercount 7)
```

I want it to come out together like a stomach.
Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try like this:

```
class CounselAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('show_firm_url', 'counsel_idx', 'show_firm_url', 'answer_count', 'counsel_status', 'deleted', 'register_date',)
    search_fields = ('counsel_status',)
    list_filter = ('counsel_status',)

    def show_firm_url(self, obj):
        return format_html("<a href='/admin/counsel/view/{0}'>{1}(answercount {2})</a>", obj.counsel_idx, obj.counsel_title, obj.answer_count)

    show_firm_url.short_description = 'title'
```